# c# prosses run python script

Tags: python, c#, winforms

**c# prosses run python script**

i try to run python file  using c# but it is not running

my error is

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified
> executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
>
> at
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
> startInfo)

this is my code

```
        try
        {
            Process cmd = new Process();

            string filePath = currentDirectory;
            string pingcmd = "  " + argument1 + " " + argument2 + "   ";
            cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = currentDirectory;
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/xx.py";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(708);
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = pingcmd;
            cmd.Start();
            string allData = "";
            int i = 0;

            while (!cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                MessageBox.Show(line);             
            }
            cmd.WaitForExit();
      

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Nothing to trim . is my complete code

Comment: Typically you use the python executable to run your python script. Are you attempting to run your script directly, as if it was self-executable?

Answer (score 0):

i found good code to do it'

```
private void run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
{
     ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
     start.FileName = "my/full/path/to/python.exe";
     start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
     start.UseShellExecute = false;
     start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
     {
         using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
         {
             string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
             Console.Write(result);
         }
     }
}
```